# jQuery - can't disable a textarea

Tags: jquery

Simple situation, but I can't get it to work. I have a checkbox and a text area. What I want is when the uses checks the checkbox, it enables the text area, when the user unchecks the box, I want the text area to be disabled. Simple right? I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

HTML:

```
<!-- Checkbox -->
<input type="checkbox" name="placeInvoiceOnHold" id="id_placeInvoiceOnHold">

<!-- Textarea -->
<textarea id="id_invoiceHoldReason" rows="10" cols="40" name="invoiceHoldReason" class="text-field"></textarea>
```

jQuery at bottom of page, in a `<script></script>` block:

```
function check_holds() {
  if ($("#id_placeInvoiceOnHold").is(":checked")) {
    $("#id_invoiceHoldReason").attr('disabled',true);
  }
  else {
    $("#id_invoiceHoldReason").removeAttr('disabled');
  }
}
```

I have tried adding a bit of code to see if my `.click` method was firing and actually handling the right element, and it is. Something like this:

```
function check_holds() {
  if ($("#id_placeInvoiceOnHold").is(":checked")) {
    $("#id_invoiceHoldReason").text("TESTING"); <!-- <<-- This line here as a a text  -->
    $("#id_invoiceHoldReason").attr('disabled',true);
  }
  else {
    $("#id_invoiceHoldReason").removeAttr('disabled');
  }
}
```

The "TESTING" shows up in the text area, so I know I have the right element ID. But seriously, why isn't it working?! I've looked at the Chrome console and there are no errors popping up.

This is what Ive tried:

```
$("#id_invoiceHoldReason").prop('disabled','disabled');
$("#id_invoiceHoldReason").disabled = true;
```

None seem to work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
$('#id_invoiceHoldReason').prop('disabled', true);
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R42qj/)

Comment: Sweet this worked. I must have had something else in my code for it to not work the first time. THx!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#id_placeInvoiceOnHold').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

or

```
$('#id_placeInvoiceOnHold').prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#id_invoiceHoldReason").attr("disabled","disabled"); 
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/txGvL/1/